# Validate CSS 2.1 with external google CSS

Tags: w3c, css

I'm using a CSS file from the Google API:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruthie" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ruthie';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Ruthie'), local('Ruthie-Regular'),
  url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ruthie/v3/Di1LdjRzoaEvDmrQy1l_ww.woff') format('woff');
}
```

However the W3C CSS validator returns 4 errors:

```
1) Value Error : font-family Property font-family doesn't exist 
   in CSS level 2.1 but exists in [css1, css2, css3] : 'Ruthie'

2) ...
```

You can check all errors by validating the page http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruthie

So my questions are:

1) How can I validate using a different CSS version like 2? Is this a good approach?

2) How can I fix these errors, eventually using a similar font and removing this API?

3) Also I would like to understand exactly why this CSS is not valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [validate CSS level 3](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruthie&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=), the code provided by Google is valid CSS3. This isn't valid CSS 2.1 code since there's no @font-face in the [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/). `@font-face` is defined in [CSS Fonts Module Level 3: 4.1 The @font-face rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule).

The `@font-face` rule was already defined in [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/fonts.html#font-descriptions), but obviously didn't make it into CSS2.1. So there's no way to validate the stylesheet in CSS2.1, only in CSS3 or CSS2.

Comment: OK, but how can I tell from the CSS to the validator to validate using level 3? I would like that http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer works fine on my page.